# Compare tools for Android Application testing between Appium and MonkeyTalk

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium, monkeytalk

I'm brand new to Mobile application automation. So, I did a research for selecting a good automation tool for test Android applications.

I need a tool with following requirements

- Functional testing
- UI testing for different devices, different Android versions
- Can write scripts using Java

According to my reading Appium is the best option for functional testing. Can someone give a comment about the best testing tool to cover both functional and UI testing.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium is a cross-platform tool and works for hybrid as well as native apps where as MonkeyTalk doesn't support hybrid apps.